# Do 'set operations' have an prescribed order of execution, or do they execute in order of evaluation?

Tags: sql, operator-precedence, set-operations

Do set operations have a prescribed order of execution (e.g. first UNION, then MINUS, then INTERSECT), or do they execute in the order of which they are scripted and evaluated?

For example, let's say I want to have a starting cohort of customer_ids, then remove some, and then add some back in. Will the set operators execute here as Qry 1 minus Qry 2 union Qry 3?

```
select cust_id from tbl A
MINUS
select cust_id  from tbl B where field = 'abc'
UNION
select cust_id from tbl A where field = 'xyz'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All set operators have equal precedence. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries004.htm#SQLRF52323) says

> If a SQL statement contains multiple set operators, then Oracle Database evaluates them from the left to right unless parentheses explicitly specify another order.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't specify the RDBMS, I'll add SQL Server for completeness. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql) is the order of operations:

1. Expressions in parentheses
2. The INTERSECT operator
3. EXCEPT (equivalent of Oracle MINUS) and UNION evaluated from left to right based on their position in the expression

Answer (score 1):

Well, not exactly "order of execution".  SQL queries represent the *result set*. 
 They specify neither the exact operations being run nor the order of execution.

That said, there is an order of precedence for set operations.  So, your query is going to be interpreted as:

```
(select cust_id from tbl A
 MINUS
 select cust_id  from tbl B where field = 'abc'
)
UNION
select cust_id from tbl A where field = 'xyz'
```

This is specified by -- or more accurately, interpreted from -- the ANSI rules on set operations.

Just because the query is *interpreted* this way does not mean that it is *executed* this way.